# Cant trigger a view's breakpoint in django tests

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I want to debug a view that gets triggered inside a django tests.py
Here's the view code:

```
def test_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        with open("a_path_to_the_file/aaa.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("done!")
```

Here's the test:

```
class ViewsTests(TestCase):
    def test_add_address(self):
        self.client.post(reverse("address_book:test_view"))
```

The view just doesn't run in that way. I want the file to be created after I run the test. The breakpoint is set on the `if request.method == "POST":` line.
I use pycharm and run tests via pycharnm run config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it guys! I had to add "test_server" to the ALLOWED_HOSTS list in the settings.py